# Regarding Spring MVC + JSON + autocomplete

Tags: javascript, json, spring, spring-mvc, autocomplete

When user click an item from dropdown menu and web view should pop up with multiple HTML components. Here is what I need to put on the view:

```
1. A JSON object which include a large array of data for autocomplete dropdown menu
2. Some other pojo collections for regular html component values.
```

If I use following Spring MVC controller method:

```
@RequestMapping(value="{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody Shop getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String hotelName) {

    List<Hotel> hotels = getHotelByNameLike(hotelName);

    return hotels;

}
```

And add other pojo object as `ModelAttribute`

```
@ModelAttribute("someName")
public Collection<SomeObject> populateObject() {
    return Object.getAllObjects();
}
```

Here are some questions regarding above plan:

```
1. There are two solution regarding `autocomplete`
    a. Each time user type in inputbox, generate a new `Like`query to getch similar results
    b. Use JSON to load all data to the view and let javascript to filter out the data in the memory. 
Plan be is preferred, but how can above code implement plan b?

2. Above code fails to mention `view` name which responds to the request from menu event.
3. Can above solution work out to bring both JSON object and POJO object to the same view?
```

Comment: Regarding 1.b. typically, a database processing a 'LIKE' query is frequently going to perform a lot better than doing the same type of filtering in a higher level language. YMMV, but when possible I recommend doing as much of the filtering at the database level as possible.

Comment: @Jeffrey Blake Thank you and I agree. But I have to admit our project is integrated with JPA instead of JDBC template and with some design issue, it does not perform very fast especially on large amount of data set. So I just guess there will be delay if we perform the 'Like' query(may or maybe that bad..). Who knows how google implement their autocomplete mechanism..amazing..

Comment: Google has a LOT of processing power at their disposal, and VERY smart people that, I am almost certain, have figured out creative ways to cache results.  I agree with @JeffBlake that the DB is far better suited to this, but if you have no other option I would suggest looking at jQuery UI's Autocomplete widget, which allows auto completion from a variable as well as an AJAX call.  Or, you could try to come up with a non-DB driven means to maintain/cache the auto complete list on the server-side, like maybe in-memory or a flat file.